# Laravel page loading issue The connection was reset

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a simple RestFul API using laravel 5.2, my client have shared domain so I cannot run the shell commands so I uploaded laravel via cpanel, in a directory adjacent to public_html, I have created a subdomain for laravel and place the public directory there and point the subdomain to the pulic directory. the things works fine sometime and sometime they are not, the webpage shows me the error

"The connection was reset"

please anyone can help me to sortout this issue ?

[image: its in firefox]

I also have tried this in google chrome but the issue still exist.
sometime the home page url works fine and sometime its showing this error, I have tried by removing comments from layout blade php file.

I have also tried by updating storage permissions to 777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the issue with .htaccess file, if any of you faces this issue you can add the following in your htaccess which is in the public directory

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
```

It worked like a charm for me

Thanks

Comment: It disables opcache, you don't need to do that in the .htaccess, you can instead just set `opcache.enable=0` in the php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *Xdebug* instead of *XCache* or *OPcache*, the profiler may be the issue. I'm using *Xampp*, and I found that disabling *Xdebug*'s profiler worked for me (i.e. comment out the following line from `php.ini`, or simply set it to `0`).

```
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
```

I haven't looked into changing any other profiler settings to get it to work properly, though I don't really use it anyways (at least no yet).

Note: The reason I mentioned *XCache* and *OPcache* is that they seem to be the main reasons for this error as far as I've found (see [Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36409789/820519) to fix this). PHP code within *Blade* comments also comes up a lot as a potential culprit.

Answer (score -1):

Open you php error log and check for a Fatal error that can't be catched by Laravel