# enctype="multipart/form-data" in Laravel blade causes "Connection was reset"

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-blade

I have an blade template file with form enctype="multipart/form-data". There is an input type="file" name="photo".

Whenever I try to upload a file, browser throws "The connection was reset" error.

Conf is: Ubuntu, nginx, php7.4...

Comment: You might want to check this answered solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316099/laravel-page-loading-issue-the-connection-was-reset

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, try step by step:

- check laravel logs fo details
- increate `client_max_body_size` to `128m` and restart nginx `sudo service nginx restart`
- increase `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini and restart php
- change to `opcache.enable=0` in php.ini and restart php, or add `php_flag opcache.enable Off` in your .httaccess file

Comment: Already done that :(

If i omit file upload, it work as it should. If file is attached, than this happens. The weird thing is: when I try to upload an image and click submit button, i can see two or three POST requests in access log?! If no image is selected, than it's as it should, only one POST request.

Comment: It sounds realy weird. Show, please, your PHP code and logs